# How to display record update data until next event in javascript ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

After submit input data loaded successfully in back-end server, however needed help to display "Added: id of the Country" right below submit button after success POST method that stays for few sec until server datapull function is called. POST method is success and was able to load and display data however having hard time to display success note for few sec along with retrieve data from datapull function

added below line inside ajax complete function assuming POST was success and run below line after complete

$('#optional').append('Added :' + state.id + ' of the ' + state.ctry).show(5000);},

```
HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>State Sq Mile</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" 
        src  = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    </script>
      </head>
  <body>
      <form>
          Country: <input type="text" id="ctry" name="city"><br>
          State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br>
          Area: <input type="text" id="area" name="area"><br>
          <button id="addValue">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p id='optional'></p>
        <ul id = 'entry'></ul>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

sample.js
(there are addition data pull code which i havent included)

$.ajax({
url: urlpost,
type:     'POST',
data:       {"Country":"ctry","State":"state","Area":"area"},
success:    function(state){
    $('#entry').append('<li>' +  state.ctry + ': ' + state.state + ': ' + state.area + '</li>');
error:      function(state){console.log(state);},
complete:   function () {
$('#optional').append('Added :' + state.id + ' of the ' + state.ctry).show(5000);},
setTimeout(function() { datapull()}, 6000)}
});
```

Expected HTML page output

```
Country:  <html input text>
State:  <html input text>
Area:  <html input text>

Submit <Button>

Added: id of the Country 

•   USA: Texas : 268,596.46 sq mile 
•   USA: California: 163,696.32 sq mile
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description could be a little bit more detailed. However I tried to work with what I have.

My idea is to add inside `success: function() {...` an exterior function call like this:

Inside we do 2 things, we append a paragraph with a message and we trigger another function that will be executed after `timeToHide` amount of time ( 3000ms in the example )

```
function displayMessage(target, content, timeToHide) {
  $(target).append('<p class="message">' + content + '</p>')

  return setTimeout(function() {
    $('.message').remove()
  }, timeToHide)
}
```

```
success:    function(state){
    $('#entry').append('<li>' +  state.ctry + ': ' + state.state + ': ' + state.area + '</li>'

    displayMessage($('.target', 'Succcess!', 3000))
    );
```

Here is a simple JSfiddle that should help: https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/bc60t92e/25/